# Keeping absolute flex item aligned with block div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have text and double vertical lines (||) and I want to keep them aligned at all times.

There is text ("2016") below the lines but right now when resizing the window the text slides slightly.

It is more clearly visible when you resize the window so the layout changes a little bit and text and lines are aligned to the right side.

Here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uh7ra6v5/.

```css
.verticalLine:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 0.13em solid #B9D7D9;
  border-right: 0.13em solid #B9D7D9;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.8rem;
  margin-left: 42%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.verticalLine {
  position: relative;
  width: 10%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.side {
  width: 45%;
}
.year {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #B35300;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  .year {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .side {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex rev">
  <div class="side">test
    <br>test
    <br>test</div>
  <div class="verticalLine">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="year">
  2016
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using flexbox, you can complete the layout with flex properties. There's no need for absolute positioning.

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.side {
    flex: 0 0 45%;                      /* 1 */
}
.verticalLine {
    display: flex;                      /* 2 */
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;                /* 3 */ 
    flex: 0 0 10%;                      /* 1 */
}
.verticalLine:before {
  flex: 1;                              /* 4 */
  content: "";
  border-left: 0.13em solid #B9D7D9;
  border-right: 0.13em solid #B9D7D9;
  width: 0.8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.year {
  color: #B35300;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex rev">
  <div class="side">test<br>test<br>test</div>
  <div class="verticalLine">
       <div class="year">2016</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uh7ra6v5/1/)

Notes:

1. Simplify code by combining `flex-shrink` and `width` from original code.
2. Make lines element a nested flex container in column-direction. Both the lines (a pseudo-element) and the text (a DOM element) are child elements and can accept flex properties.
3. Horizontally center the lines and text.
4. Lines consume all available space in the container.